# sqlalchemy using generators in and_ filters

Tags: sqlalchemy, generator

I'm trying to get a search going, where I pass in several different syllables into the 'and_' function via a generator. My search should then return all and only those words that have all given syllables

matches = db.session.query(Word).join(Word.syllables).filter(db.and_(Syllable.syllable==(syl for syl in combo))).all()

This doesn't return anything currently. Does this approach even make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this query will do what you want.  The query you'd generate would be something like this for combo = (1, 2):

```
SELECT words.* FROM words INNER JOIN syllables ON words.id = syllables.word_id WHERE syllables.syllable = 1 AND syllables.syllable = 2
```

What I think you want is this for combo = (1, 2):

```
SELECT words.* FROM words INNER JOIN syllables AS s1 ON words.id = s1.word_id AND s1.syllable = 1 INNER JOIN syllables AS s2 ON words.id = s2.word_id AND s2.syllable = 2
```

Repeated joining might get slow but here is how you could do this in sqlalchemy:

```
query = db.session.query(Word)
for syl in combo:
    syl_cls = aliased(Syllable)
    query = query.join(syl_cls, Word.syllables).filter(syl_cls.syllable == syl)
matches = query.all()
```

If you were generating OR clauses then this query would be a lot simpler.